# Making an http call inside of switchmap

Tags: rxjs, observable

I am writing an angular app with firebase auth and a dotnet core backend.  I am trying to create a service so that i can track the firebase uid and track if the user is an admin (which is obtained from the backend server).  I can successfulyl get the uid from firebase with no issue, but when i try to get the user object from my api I get errors in the console.

[image]

Here is my code in my user service:

```
export class UserService {
    uid = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
        map(authState => {
            return !authState ? null : authState.uid;
        })
    );

    isAdmin = this.uid.pipe(
        switchMap(uid => {
            if (uid) {
                console.log("there is a uid")
                this.httpClient.get<User>("https://localhost:44337/api/users/" + uid).subscribe(data => {
                    console.log(data.isAdmin); // prints 'true'
                    return observableOf(data.isAdmin);
                });
            } else {
                return observableOf(false);
            }
        })
    );

    constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a switchMap operator you should not directly subscribe to an observable. You should return the observable and the switchMap operator will handle the subscription for you.

```
switchMap(uid => {
            if (uid) {
                console.log("there is a uid")
                return this.httpClient.get<User>("https://localhost:44337/api/users/" + uid).pipe(map(data => {
                    console.log(data.isAdmin); // prints 'true'
                    return data.isAdmin
                }));
            } else {
                return of(false);
            }
        })
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  That was so simple!